# Catching market search intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to catch an Android Market search intent.

That's the way you launch Android Market and search for an app by package name:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.google.somepackage")));
```

Now, here's the intent filter for one of my activities:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="market" android:host="search" />
</intent-filter>
```

I'd expect Android to ask me which app should handle the intent which doesn't happen.
Yet, if I replace `market` with `market1` or `search` with `search1`, in both places, my activity gets launched.
Is there a notion of "untouchable" intents or something?

TIA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is odd indeed, and kinda goes against the whole open intent system.  I know there are broadcasts that only the system can create, but I hadn't heard of such a thing for intent resolution.

Anyway, I just dumped the Market APK on my HTC Hero and checked the manifest.  They're being slightly more specific in their URI-matching by adding the path:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="100">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" 
          android:host="market.android.com" android:path="/search" />
    <data android:scheme="market"
          android:host="search" android:path="" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, I tried adding this to my app, except I increased the priority value ([not that I've seen that have any effect before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960249/intent-filter-with-androidpriority-setting/1977942#1977942)), yet still I couldn't capture the `Intent`.

Hopefully someone (or the AOSP) can shed some light on the situation...

Comment: By setting the priority like this, no third party application can intercept the intent.  Only apps installed in the system partition can be granted a priority > 0.

Comment: @hackbod would be nice if that could be added to the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#priority

Comment: Mirko: I filed a bug yesterday on the Android issue list pointing to this comment :)

Comment: Just to add some more data on this. It appears that apps *not* on the system partition *can* define a `<receiver>` with a priority greater than 0. This causes the broadcasts to be ordered and received before the system apps. Note that I haven't tried this with an `<activity>` as mentioned in the question.

Comment: you are right @Christopher, I am using a ordered `BroadcastReceiver` just like that. Contrary to what hackbod implies, there is indeed a difference between ordered and non-ordered broadcasts and it is very much possible to have a priority less then 100 (even 0) for a ordered broadcast. There's an excellent post about the differences and behaviour on the android-developers site, read it here: http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html