# Open my android app when pressing Android Market url

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to capture the event when the user clicks an Android Market url so I can have it start my app instead of Market.

I have tried to use intent-filters like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023811/catching-market-search-intents) post but I can't get it to work, it never opens my application.

Comment: I imagine Android would be incredibly vulnerable if you could do this.

Comment: I agree - don't inhibit the user from using Google Market, if your app is similar provide an icon like usual. This sounds like a virus I recently got :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read [the accepted answer from the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023811/catching-market-search-intents/2024222#2024222) and its comments, you would find that you cannot intercept these `Intents`. They are protected by the firmware.