# Making the app receives Market links?

Tags: android, google-play, receiver

When you are in some application, say Twitter, and you share an android application's link, I want my app to be in the list of the intent receivers.

I know I need to add a [receiver](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) but what do I need to add inside this tag to make my activity just like the Market.

Note: My application is not a Market-like app. I just want to allow the user of my app to give me any other app's link.

Comment: Have you seen this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023811/catching-market-search-intents

Comment: Although some people said it didn't work but I'll give it a try and come back.

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("URL")));
```

Comment: This isn't what I want. What you wrote is how you fire an intent which will be catch by applications like the Market. I want my application `to catch the intent not to fire it`.