# android intent filter with multiple app for the same mime type

Tags: android, android-intent, filter

Hi I build two apps to handle the same mime type, I want one app to have higher priority, so if both app installed on the android device, app A will always be selected, if only one is installed, and that one will be picked.
Currently if I use the intent filter on the same mime type, Android will show the App selection instead. So how do I specify a priority so that when both app installed, the higher priority one will be picked instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a priority for the intent filter? Look at the [android:priority](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#priority) attribute of .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that setting priority for the intent filters does not work for third party apps. It works only for the apps that are installed in the system partition.

Also the android:priority tag works only for the ordered broadcasts.
please refer to this:
[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023811/catching-market-search-intents#comment-1947212)